# How to insert data from one object to another with different structure to generate third object

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I'm trying to extract data from an object and insert this data into another object, but the two objects have different structures. And its very large object, more than 3000 lines.

I need to check in object1 if `dictionary[0].key.mcp[0]` exists and if it exists in object2 `conv[0].mcp` I need to insert the 4 languages: German, Swedish, Chinese and Japanese in to the object1 `dictionary[0].dicts` and if it doesn't exist, then do nothing

I think maybe with a for loop I will be able to accomplish task but the problem is that in some cases below the key the value `mcp` changes for another.

Object 1

```
dictionary = [
  {
    "key": {
      "mcp": [
        "mcp.empty"
      ]
    },
    "dicts": {
      "english": "",
      "german": ""
    },
    "context": null,
    "tags": [],
    "edited": "2016-10-27T15:41:31.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key": {
      "mcp": [
        "ui.controls.plasmacontrol.feeder"
      ]
    },
    "dicts": {
      "english": "Feeder",
      "german": "Förderer"
    },
    "context": null,
    "tags": [],
    "edited": "2016-10-27T15:41:31.000Z"
  },
```

Object 2

```
var conv = [
    {
        "mcp": "mcp.empty",
        "english": "",
        "german": "",
        "Swedish": "",
        "chinese": "",
        "japanese": ""
    },
    {
        "mcp": "ui.controls.plasmacontrol.feeder",
        "english": "Feeder",
        "german": " Förderer ",
        "Swedish": "Transportör",
        "chinese": "送粉器",
        "japanese": "粉末供給装置"
    },
    {
        "mcp": "ui.controls.plasmacontrol.feeder1",
        "english": "Feeder 1",
        "german": "Förderer 1 ",
        "Swedish": "Transportör 1",
        "chinese": "1号送粉器",
        "japanese": "粉末供給装置1"
    },
```

The expected result is an object with all the data inserted from object1 to object2.

Object 3 (Expected result)

```
 dictionary = [
      {
        "key": {
          "mcp": [
            "mcp.empty"
          ]
        },
        "dicts": {
         "english": "",
            "german": "",
            "Swedish": "",
            "chinese": "",
            "japanese": ""
        },
        "context": null,
        "tags": [],
        "edited": "2016-10-27T15:41:31.000Z"
      },
      {
        "key": {
          "mcp": [
            "ui.controls.plasmacontrol.feeder"
          ]
        },
        "dicts": {
          "english": "Feeder 1",
            "german": "Förderer 1 ",
            "Swedish": "Transportör 1",
            "chinese": "1号送粉器",
            "japanese": "粉末供給装置1"
        },
        "context": null,
        "tags": [],
        "edited": "2016-10-27T15:41:31.000Z"
      },
```

Until now I have this and is returning some errors

```
import dictionary from "./dictionary.mjs";
import conv from "./converted.mjs";
import _ from "lodash";
import fs from "fs";
import util from 'util';


const newObject = _.map(dictionary, dictionaryItem => {
   const key = _.get(dictionaryItem, "key.mcp[0]", "")
   const isPresent = _.find(conv, { "mcp": key })
   if(isPresent) {
     /*  console.log('se hizo') */
      return { ...dictionaryItem, dicts: { 
             "english": isPresent.english,
            "german": isPresent.german,
            "Swedish": isPresent.Swedish,
            "chinese": isPresent.chinese,
            "japanese": isPresent.japanese
         } 
      }
  } else {
/*    console.log('no') */
         return dictionary
  }
})  

try {
   const data = fs.writeFileSync('./final.js', util.inspect(newObject, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
   //file written successfully
 } catch (err) {
   console.error(err)
 }
```

Comment: Can you show what have you done?

Comment: Where do the Chinese, Japanese and Swedish texts come from?

Comment: Can you create a sample object showing your exact expected result? Plus, are you going to compare each array by index? Because in your sample, the first object has 3 items and the next object has 2 items.

Comment: HI, @JackBashford, comes from an excel file I prevously converted to json.

Comment: Hi @AbanaClara I posted the expected results now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) 
First import where you want to perform the operation

```
import _ from "lodash"
  or
const _ = require("lodash")
```

And

```
const newObject = _.map(dictionary, dictionaryItem => {
   const key = _.get(dictionaryItem, "key.mcp[0]", "")
   const isPresent = _.find(conv, { "mcp": key })
   if(isPresent) {
      return { ...dictionaryItem, dicts: { 
             "english": isPresent.english,
            "german": isPresent.german,
            "Swedish": isPresent.Swedish,
            "chinese": isPresent.chinese,
            "japanese": isPresent.japanese
         } 
      }
  } else {
         return dictionary
  }
})
```

OMG you got your desire result

Comment: Hi thanks! @Ashok it is really close but I have a problem, the newObject repeats many dictionaryItems and write the items in another order, and don't write all of them, then when I write the newObject to another file at a cerain point says ...2730 more items and then start the file again.

Comment: @ErnestoPérez  If you are not using the async function Order problem not come out and you can use _.map more then 10000 items only drawback increase item also increase the time of execution.

Comment: I Posted what I have now it has like 35.000 lines the entire file

Comment: It worked for me on 10000 record and save object into final.js file without error